# axois react-keycloak/web token in inteceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I'm trying to use a request inteceptor with react-keycloak/web - however i get an array of errors when doing so.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';

const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com/api/v1/',
  timeout: 30000,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `${keycloak.token}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

but i get:

> React Hook "useKeycloak" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Now i have of course tried to create a function with for example GetToken():

```js
function GetToken() {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  return keycloak.token
}
```

but doing so leaves me with:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use react hooks out of react tree.

You can export axoios instance and import it elsewhere inside react (eg: App.js) and set interceptors there.

for example:

```
import axiosIns from 'api';
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import WholeApp from "WholeApp";

const App = () => {
    const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

    useEffect(() => {
        axiosIns.interceptors.request.use(
            (config) => {
                config.headers.Authorization = `${keycloak.token}`;
                return config;
            },
            (error) => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    }, []);

    return <WholeApp />;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'm getting errors on ReactKeycloakProvider - i'm not sure where this is supposed be created if we are wrapping the entire application around this.

Comment: actually, i have this working - i could initialise ReactKeycloakProvider  in the ReactDom.render() which seems to work.

Comment: @RyanGough could you provide your solution for `errors on ReactKeycloakProvider`